# How to delegate a property in a class with its other property's same property in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin, properties, delegates

How to delegate a property in a class with its other property's same property in Kotlin? In other words, is there a simple way to replace the code below?

```
var someProperty: Type
    get() = otherMember.someProperty
    set(value) { otherMember.someProperty = value }
```

I could't find any info about this from [the official 
 docs for Delegated Propeties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) like this:

```
interface IA {
    var someProperty: String
}

class A : IA {
    override var someProperty: String = ""
        get() {
            println("get by otherMember")
            return field
        }
        set(value) {
            println("set by otherMember")
            field = value
        }
}

class B(private val otherMember:A) : IA by otherMember

fun main() {
    val b = B(A())
    b.someProperty = "test" // prints "set by otherMember"
    println(b.someProperty) // prints "get by otherMember" "test"
}
```

Comment: But here comes the problem: in my case `class A` is an internal Java API so I can't modify what interfaces it implements.